# O que significa o operador !! em um return

Tags: javascript, typescript

Eu sei que a exclamação (`!`) é a negação da minha expressão, mas na minha função tem duas exclamações, exemplo:

```
public get isChecarAlgo() {
    return !!this.algumValorNumerico;
}
```

Nesse caso, o que significa? Que o retorno será `true` ou `false` dependendo de ter ou não valor?

Comment: É um truque safado pra converter um valor ou ausência deste em booleano. As duas exclamações servem pra negar a negação. Então, se tiver valor o resultado vai ser true e, caso contrário, será false.

Comment: Eu imaginei... Muito obrigado por confirmar!

Comment: Esse "truqe" é usado quando o valor é **truthy** ou **falsy** para fazer uma rápida conversão. Semelhante ao que alguns minificadores usam para diminuir aonde se escreve explicitamente true e false, como disso `let x = true, y=false;` para isso `let x=!0, y=!1;`

Comment: Só pra constar que isso é uma característica do JavaScript - como o TypeScript é um *superset* do JS, acaba tendo isso "por tabela".